# Inverse Image Example of Mendelson

Tags: functions

In 'Introduction to Topology' by B. Mendelson we have an example of inverse images as follows:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = x² - x - 2$.

If $X$ is the closed interval $[1,2]$, then $f(X) = [-2,0]$. If $Z$ is the open interval $(-1,1)$, then $f(Z) = \left(-\frac{9}{4},0 \right) \cup \left\{-\frac{9}{4}\right\}$. $f^{1}([-2,0]) = [1,2] \cup [-1,0]$. $f^{-1} (\{ 0\} ) = \{ 2, -1 \}$ is the set of roots of the polynomial $x² - x - 2$. $f^{-1}([-5, -4]) = \varnothing$.

My questions are: why the image of the open interval $(-1,1)$ is $\left(-\frac{9}{4},0 \right) \cup \left\{-\frac{9}{4}\right\}$ and not $(-2,0)$?  And if the inverse images are the elements in the domain that map to $f(x)$, then why has he added the interval $[-1,0]$ to $f^{-1}([2,0])$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is going on, but $f(Z)=(-\frac{9}{4},0)$. As for $f^{-1}([-2,0])$, by definition we have
$$f^{-1}([-2,0])=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)\in[-2,0]\}=[-1,0]\cup[1,2].$$

Comment: I made mistakes with the inequalities when trying to find out the intervals, but thanks!